# storing data in dynamodb: slow process

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am trying to store a pandas dataframe with around 70k rows in dynamodb.
I am using the following process:

```
#initial schema
primary_key='column1'
order_key='column2'
keyschema = [{'AttributeName': primary_key, 'KeyType': 'HASH'}, {'AttributeName': order_key, 'KeyType': 'RANGE'}]
attributesdefinitions = [{'AttributeName': primary_key, 'AttributeType': 'S'}, {'AttributeName': order_key, 'AttributeType': 'S'}]    

#create table
dynamodb_client = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='eu-north-1')
_ = dynamodb_client.create_table(
        TableName='tablename',
        KeySchema=keyschema,
        AttributeDefinitions=attributesdefinitions,
        ProvisionedThroughput={'ReadCapacityUnits': 5, 'WriteCapacityUnits': 5})
dynamodb_client.get_waiter('table_exists').wait(TableName='tablename')

#store data
dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb", region_name='eu-north-1')
dynamodb_table = dynamodb.Table('tablename')
with dynamodb_table.batch_writer() as batch:
    for index, row in pandas_df.iterrows():
        batch.put_item(Item={'column1': row['column1'],
                             'column2': row['column2'],
                             'anothercolumn': row['column3'])
```

It works but for these 70000 rows its running like 5 hours now and havent finished.
If I increase the `WriteCapacityUnits` I assume it will take less time but costs increases. But this writing process is scheduled once per week. So I dont want to pay for higher writecapacity when most of the time will be only for reading this table.
But gennerally it seems super slow for just 70k rows. Any insights?

**edit**

write plot(write goes to zero cause i stopped the process):

[image]

throttling plot(at around 14:00 i changed to writecapacity from 5 to 10):

[image]

Comment: Look in your table > metrics tab in the AWS console. Does it show any throttling? and does it show writes happening?

Comment: @Mulhoon thanks for the comment. I have updated the answer with the plots

Comment: If this only happens once a week you may want to try switching to on-demand capacity, to only pay for what you use, and you don't need to worry about provisioning.